# recursive prime factors in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, recursion, prime-factoring

I can see that my function does successfully find prime factors, but the format of my output shows me that I'm going about this problem in the wrong way still.

I'm trying to figure out recursion but haven't actually had any instruction on how to go about it. I understand the general ideas of base cases and finding the recursive step (because I previously learned proof by induction in college) but I struggle finding the right way to structure the output of my function when it involves things that are not simple numbers, like arrays. I would like for someone to point me in the right direction for why fundamentally my code isn't quite working here.

Also, it seems that adding nil and then deleting nil is not very elegant, but I'm not sure what else my base case would be.

```
def get_prime_factors(num)
  return nil if num <= 1
  factors = []
  (2..num).each do |k| 
    if prime?(k) && num % k == 0
      factors << k
      factors << get_prime_factors(num / k)
      break
    end
  end
  factors.delete(nil)
  factors
end

def prime?(num)
  return false if num < 2
  (2...num).none? { |k| num % k == 0}
end
```

Comment: `get_prime_factors` returns a list in the recursive step but expects a single element on line 7. I assume you meant to return `[]` in the base case and use `+=` rather than `<<` in the recursive call.

Comment: Getting primes is not the most natural fit for recursion, I think. Something like generating the Fibonacci sequence is more natural.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing App Academy's free, open bootcamp, and their solution is as follows:

```
def get_prime_factors(num)
    (2...num).each do |fact|
        if (num % fact == 0) #=> in below return, if num was 60: 2, 2, 3
            other_fact = num / fact  #=> in below return, if num was 60: 30->15->5
            return [ *get_prime_factors(fact), *get_prime_factors(other_fact) ]
        end
    end
    [num] #=> if num was 60: [2, 2, 3, 5]
end
```

Any prime argument will automatically get printed in `[num]` at the end, never entering the if statement. That combines with the return statement to replace an initial base case. Though the base case doesn't appear explicitly, it's `num` being prime. To figure the base case, imagine not the smallest number, but arguments that the method would not be able to reduce further (such as 2 or 7).

The following is more for other people looking this up.

This problem is hard if you're just learning recursion. I almost never give up and look at the solution without solving a problem, and I had to give up. In addition to the base case subversion, another tricky thing is that nothing is decremented. On top of that, it counts up, enclosing the recursive countdown inside a count-up loop.

So if you struggled with this, you're not alone.